# Java in BlueJ does not execute main class

Tags: java, bluej

I am using the BlueJ IDE. I have a main class entitled `ProgramOne`, and another class `StarTurtle` (intended to serve an instance method).

Here is the code of `ProgramOne`:

```
        public class ProgramOne
        {
     public static void main (String[ ] args) {  
          StarTurtle turtle1 = new StarTurtle();
          int result = turtle1.StartTurtle(5);

     }
}
```

Here is the code of `StarTurtle`:

```
public class StarTurtle 
{ 

private int points;      

public int StartTurtle(int x) 
{ 
points = x; 

Turtle sue;
sue = new Turtle();
sue.paint (90, 40); 

} 

}
```

(The `turtle` method you see is from two other classes that I have not pasted here for the sake of brevity. These classes are found in the http://www.cs.ccsu.edu/~jones/book.htm manual)

The code only compiles, and there is no option to execute. However, there is no option to execute `void main (String[ ] args)`, which there should be to execute the main class. Does anyone know what is the cause of this? I am assuming that there is a problem in the code itself. The `StarTurtle` class does execute, but the main class `ProgramOne` does not, which leads me to believe that the problem lies in the `ProgramOne` class.

When I mean "option to execute", I am referring to this BlueJ functionality:

[image: BlueJ]

Answer (score 0):

When you call the main method from the class ProgramOne, you have created an instance of StarTurtle turtle1. But when you assign value in result variable by calling turtle1.StartTurtle(5) method, nothing is stored in that variable. The problem is that you have issue in this function in your StarTurtle class. You have defined public int StartTurtle(int x) function as return type but actually it is not returning any thing. Therefore, you need to add a return statement on that block of code.

```
public class StarTurtle { 
    private int points; 
    public int StartTurtle(int x){ 
        points = x; 
        Turtle sue;
        sue = new Turtle();
        sue.paint (90, 40); 
        return points;
    } 
}
```

However, on the other hand, your class and functions are incorrect though they are working. You classes should be like this.

```
public class ProgramOne{
     public static void main (String[ ] args) {  
          StarTurtle turtle1 = new StarTurtle();
          turtle1.StartTurtle();
     }
}

public class StarTurtle { 
    //Void type of method instead of previous return type
    public void StartTurtle(){ 
        Turtle sue;
        sue = new Turtle();
        sue.paint (900, 550); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your tips, however, the main class still does not execute.

Comment: Did you try to execute new ProgramOne() or the main method (void main(String[] args)? If you executed ProgramOne() then nothing will execute since you have not initialized any constructor in the ProgramOne class. If you execute the main function, I'm sure that program will execute successfully. OR if you want to execute the main class calling new ProgramOne() function, you must initialize the constructor.

Comment: There's no option to do either, because BlueJ seems to think that there is an error. @ranjit kaliraj

Comment: what type of error? I'm afraid, but if there is some compiler issues in your code try and test with above codes that I mentioned. I have executed that successfully in my BlueJ.